# Reshaping a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I've tried looking for a solution for this on the website, but reshaping data continues to baffle me. I hope someone can help out! :)
Basically, my data looks like this:

```
Item Condition1 Condition2 Condition3
A    1          2          3
B    1          2          3
C    1          2          3
D    1          2          3
```

And I want it to look like this

```
Item Condition
A    1
A    2
A    3
B    1
B    2
B    3
C    1
C    2
C    3
D    1
D    2
D    3
```

From what I understand, it seems possible to do this in more than one way, but I have yet to discover one that works!

Comment: What are the ways that you've tried that *haven't* worked, because, yes, this can be done in several ways.

Comment: And when your output has A 1, A 2, A 3, is the 1 / 2 / 3 because the value in the column, or the number in the column header Condition1 / Condition2 / Condition3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. There are several ways to do this in R. Here are a few.

Options which get the order you specify in your question

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, list(Condition = unlist(.SD)), by = Item]
```

---

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = "Condition", 
             sep = "var.stubs")[, .time_1 := NULL][]
```

---

```
data.frame(Item = rep(mydf[[1]], 
                      each = ncol(mydf[-1])), 
           Condition = c(t(mydf[-1])))
```

Options which require one more step to either drop columns or reorder rows

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar = "Item",
        varying = 2:ncol(mydf), sep = "")
```

---

```
cbind(mydf[1], stack(mydf[-1]))
```

---

```
library(tidyr)
gather(mydf, var, val, Condition1:Condition3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require(reshape2)

df<-data.frame(Item=LETTERS[1:4],
               Condition1=1,
               Condition2=2,
               Condition3=3)
reshapedf<-melt(df,id=1)[-2]
reshapedf<-reshapedf[with(reshapedf,order(Item)),]
colnames(reshapedf)[2]<-"Condition"
```

I am sure that there are other ways to do this. Explore and have fun :)